# Validating for uniqueness in MongoAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, mongoalchemy

I am trying to ensure name uniqueness in a MongoAlchemy-backed model, and am uncertain how to go about it.

My first attempt involved writing a wrap validator which checked for existing database entries with the same `name` and checked against them (to ensure that there were either 0 or 1 entries with the same name), but this failed because the validator only receives the string with the `name`, not the entire object (so comparing `mongo_id`s was impossible).

What's the best way to ensure that objects of a single class all have unique `name`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a unique index.

http://www.mongoalchemy.org/api/schema/document.html#mongoalchemy.document.Index

```
>>> class Person(Document):
...     name = StringField()
...     name_index = Index().ascending('name').unique()
```

The database will enforce the constraint for you.  It's just wrapping the code that mongo already has here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

Comment: You're the best, Jeff. You still haven't accepted my pull request though... :p